# How to split string at index[0] of each sublist, and have each split index in it's own original list?

Tags: python, string, list, split, sublist

How could you split a string at index 0 of all sublists into separate elements, and have each of the split elements be contained within a copy of the original sublist?

For example:

```
Original_List = [['a,b','c','d','e','f'],['1','2','3'],['z,y','1','2']]
```

Desired Result:

```
Desired_List = [['a','c','d','e','f'],['b','c','d','e','f'],['1','2','3'],['z','1','2'],['y','1','2']]
```

Also, to add further clarity with one more actual example:

```
Original_List = [['Contract_ID1,Contract_ID2','Amount','Date'],['Contract_ID3,Contract_ID4','400','Jan1']]
```

I want every sublist to have only one Contract_ID, but still have the Amount and Date Associated with it

```
Desired_List =  [['Contract_ID1','Amount','Date'],['Contract_ID2','Amount','Date'],['Contract_ID3','400','Jan1'],['Contract_ID4','400','Jan1']]
```

I can split all strings at index 0 of all sublists with the below, but I can't figure out how I would duplicate the whole list for each split element and then replace the strings that were split with the split element, so that each split element had its own list.

```
Split_First_Indices_of_Sublists = map(lambda x: x[0].split(","),Original_List)
>>[['a', 'b'], ['1'], ['z', 'y']]
for x in Original_List:
     x.pop(0)
>> [['c', 'd', 'e', 'f'], ['2', '3'], ['1', 2]]
```

Comment: Do you have mixed types or is the 2 a typo ?

Comment: What's the problem to solve behind it?

Comment: should `Desired_List` also contain `['b','c','d','e','f']`?

Comment: Isn't `['b','c','d','e','f']` missing from your desired output?

Comment: Sorry guys, you are correct that ['b','c','d','e','f'] should have been included. I added an additional more concrete example to add more clarity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's clearest written out as explicit loops:

```
Desired_List = []

for li in Original_List:
    for spl in li[0].split(','):
        Desired_List.append([spl] + li[1:])
```

gives:

```
Desired_List
Out[153]: 
[['a', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'],
 ['b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'],
 ['1', '2', '3'],
 ['z', '1', '2'],
 ['y', '1', '2']]
```

And of course you can immediately turn this into the equivalent one-line list comp:

```
[[spl] + li[1:] for li in Original_List for spl in li[0].split(',')]
```

Which may or may not be less readable, depending on the reader :-)

And as a last note, make sure that this is the data structure you really want.  A `dict` keyed by `Contract_ID` seems like a very natural structure for your end product.

Comment: My biggest concern is speed/efficiency as I'm performing this on a large list. This definitely does the job, but I'm wondering how to make speed improvements. Let me know if you have any thoughts on this.

Comment: @Chris the list-comp version is probably about as efficient as this can be done.  There is some optimization possible in the list concatenation part (`[spl] + li[1:]`) but the string splitting operation can't really be sped up and is likely accounting for much of the run time.  If you really need to optimize, I suggest digging in with a profiler and seeing where the majority of time is being spent.

Comment: That's not to say that this *problem* can't be sped up, just your current *operation*.  If you were to move to a real database system or a vectorized system (like `numpy`) then sure, this can be done really fast.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about numpy and profiler! I will be looking into both of those not just for this but for many other functions i need to run.I'm not sure how I would do this in numpy yet (let me know if you have any thoughts on this), but I'll look into it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
Original_List=[['a,b','c','d','e','f'],['1','2','3'],['z,y','1','2']]
desired_list=[]
for p in pl:
    try:
        splited=p.split(',')
        if not type(splited) is list:
            splited=[splited]
        if count(splited)>1:
            for list in splited:
                p[0]=list
                desired_list.append(p)
        else:
            desired_list.append()
    except:
        pass
```